# Google map canvas dynamically resize on click

Tags: css, google-maps, resize

I would really appreciate some help with a google maps issue.
All I have is a basic understanding of HTML and CSS, so please be patient with me.
**I am trying to make a google maps canvas dynamically increase and decrease in height when you click a button.**
I have managed to do this so far... [HERE](http://www.clippertonproject.com/xxx/2014/03/19/wteyn/)
But once resized my map laves grey space in the new height?!?
I have also found exactly the kind of thing I need here... [HERE](http://leonardogandini.com/projects/Google-Maps-API/map-resize)
But the code is a little confusing and I cant seam to get a version of this working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this function after you update the map dimensions.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

In the second link you provided, they are calling the above function after the map canvas is set to a new dimension:

```
$('#resizeuno').click(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').css({'width':'300','height':'400'});
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');  
});
```

Comment: Thanks Briggs this is perfect, I now have two buttons that make my map bigger and smaller. Is there a way to make it resize dinamically?

Comment: Sorry @Briggs, I also added this to the code...
`$('#small').click(function() {
     $('#map').css({'width':'100%','height':'500', 'transition':'1s height'});
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
 });`
But I'm then left with the same problem I started with?!?

Comment: The transition should be 'height 1s' not '1s height'

Comment: this makes the resize dynamic but it doesnt reload the map on the first click. I have an example... [link](http://www.clippertonproject.com/xxx/tcp-test/).

Comment: ive got a link to the code im using, hope that helps... [link](http://www.clippertonproject.com/xxx/wp-content/themes/f8-lite/map-small.php)